# Can java annotations be overridden? If so? How?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I built a validation mechanism around my application based on java annotations - similar to [Java Bean validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303), with the sole exception that mine is easier - it has only value and the type of the value is `Float`.

```
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Min {    
   float value() default 0f; 
}
```

Now I need to extend this mechanism to support also `Integer` values. Is it possible to provide an overriding of the annotation? Something like:

```
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Min {    
   int value() default 0; 
}
```

Or is it possible that only one of two properties is present? Something like:

```
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Min {    
   float value() default 0f; 
   int intValue();
}
```

Any other mechanism is welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annotation type cannot declare a superclass or superinterface; see [JLS 9.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) for details.

Here are a couple of options:

- Modify the annotation to support two values
- Create a second annotation with a different name and value, and have your annotation processor handle both annotations.

Comment: yes I know that inheritance is not permitted with the exception of Java EE annotations that have a special statute. I think I will go with one of the two options. Now I am trying multiple ways. 10x!

Comment: Java EE annotation overriding is a different concept.  It doesn't involve inheritance in the Java language sense.  Rather, it is about the meaning of the annotations and how Java EE acts on it.